# Can i disconnect my public ip address?

Tags: networking

My IP address got hacked by my friend. As we speak my internet connection is getting slow and he also has access to my mobile data. How can I stop him from using my mobile data?

Comment: If you want a temporary solution, disconnect your router/Modem. For a permanent solution, I don't think there is a way to completely hide your public IP Address, unless you use a VPN (Which still doesn't but it helps a lot).

Comment: An IP address cannot be hacked, it’s not a thing. What really happened and why do you thunk he’s accessing your “mobile data”? What is “mobile data”? Do you perhaps mean mobile broadband access via your phone or whatever?

Comment: The IP address by itself cannot be hacked.  It is the computer/device hosting the IP that gets hacked.  Install or activate a firewall, and clean your computer of the infection.  You may have to backup all your files, and reformat your computer to clear the infection.  If your computer is using a mobile hot spot, change the password on your hotspot inside your phone.  If he hacked your router, you may have to upgrade its firmware or get a new one that isn't vulnerable.

Comment: Ask him to stop, if he doesn't he isn't your friend.  Thus call the cops on him.

Comment: Cleaning up the formatting does not make the question any clearer. The issue is that "hacked" is more or less meaningless. What evidence do you have that it was your friend? What happened before you began experiencing issues? What is using up all of your mobile data? Do you just have a virus on your phone or computer? As you'll likely have trouble describing what IS happening, start by doing your best to describe what HAS happened already, what was going on before, and what specific things or events changed.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot simply disconnect your public address and get a different one. You can hide your IP address by using a VPN. But that is not what you are looking for right now since he already got your IP Address as you say.

If you are getting a slow internet connection / DDOS-ed you can disconnect your router from the internet service provider. Then you could call your ISP to give you a different Public IP address. And tell them what happend and why you want a different IP address.

I'm not sure what you mean by Mobile Data and how that is linked to your IP address?!? Mobile Data is a subscription for **YOUR** cellphone no one can use **YOUR** subscription / data unless you have set up a hotspot for internet.

Also, For this you can call your cellphone network provider and tell them what is going on.

If you were talking about Mobile Data as the Files and Pictures that are on your phone then just disconnect your phone from the internet put your private files on your computer or USB stick and delete the data from your phone. Then call your cellphone network provider.